# Typescript mutually exclusive type inference of tuple

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have this [TS Playground set up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4&ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGygXigbynMYEQFxQDkcAzgCamFQC+A3AFADGA9gHYnBQDucAlp6gAUASgIAFAE7MAtrxIQAPPAQA+FGtYQuUSTLkRBgiRBLMEANwjD1UecAAqvaRGYBXYIevI1x0xYMYWDj4RKQUJFTUwgA0UACMAAxJwsIM9IKkIKyMUCI2aPRQUKCQUACSAKISEii2wBK8rADmUAD0rdwAFhCsxZ1yUAMl0BwNzYOcZMwmUKzMnI0AZhA1w1DMi1C+rgicLNUQjMAIIPSFmCRZOYuu2cC8bLZwy7qy8iLiUm+KANrKsawdggALpQAA+UB+gIQCFilWqwLUBSKRXqIHQ5xRUBY7E4vlqcB4-G4fA8qUxKOMwFcEl6P18AKBwIYWOo2LgwEYnVyKwk1mRWK2EGptMh0NhUF5F3KVQkzIp1HOivOOI4UCmAGUZML+s0AOr8blCCjAOAEZReJEU1VmCAAOgQzCaghNcHJRWVRVVnB+rtivOYcoJRM4JGeEFe+hEaSKvE2ggDfIxWKpNN6iZZNHOqdFmu1wF1TQNBZdHLdbQ6ynBsyBsS43V6xJInTcCDIUAARtBlPQotGzhlLtlcpbkxXuIGANYkQabRODGdwOpjFpwapwU6o8DQeE1VCjRpNH7As5FTLDm53B69MMvL5R0Q6e-yBR-RCMmGgiFQ2syhFWrE0THLFvSFGdUEJUkSX4ftBSFEU6QZGtP0zD12U5bkE2qfkKSKHM6XFf1qmlXd5VZJVT2xNg1TzZwC0PYsjVyV1zUQUcBS9ajbQdJ1S1Nd0sxVaifT9SVqkDUEIJDJ47z0d5yXOOMeXEpMOPgtMxKkCRM0VPDhQ02idQYw0+LdXthH7dJzxyPJvDHdoJwkadZ00wMF0wXpmA7AArQ5gHONZd1qDBnBIMMmhCA9xk9C4rigS8jmvGSI2fAxH0jF83wlcUvzFX9SIAlEgLUzjcTA4MoJDWDBXwyEkJy1CaHQrllNU3D1NFH8YSImpSD-OVGt0wTSpo5gtTowtGNqUzWIQdjrS43AeOdV0BKG0DfTLHqJIqptwwytKYxcrCtJwlN9NFDMKL0hD1TG-NJpM1bzOjIA)

Basically what my issue is I am trying to do a promise wrapper that returns a tuple with the result and a null or a null and an error, basically I want this to happen:

```js
const [data, error] = await safePromise(wait());
```

The issue I am having is that if I want to return the error as a string, it does not correctly infer the type of data after I check that error exists.

```js
const [data, error] = await safePromise(wait());

if (error) {
  return error;
}
return doSomethingWith(data) // Val | null, when it should be Val
```

What I found out to be mind boggling for me is that if I return a string array or an Object (something like: { message: string }), IT WORKS flawlessly. Another thing that I found out was that if I would have this same thing, but with not promise and not try catch typescript knows what's up, and correctly infers the type, what does promise do to prevent this from happening?

So I found kind of a fix this way, but I am just curious why this strange behaviour is and what can I do to fix it. And also if there is a way to tell typescript that the return value of the function is strictly a [Type, null] or [null, error] so it knows that if there is an error the Type is defined;

the implementation of safePromise:

```js
async function safePromise<T>(promise: Promise<T>) {
  try {
    const res = await promise;
    return [res, null] as const;
  } catch (err) {
    return [null, err as IErr] as const;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the wrong type guard here:

```
if (error) {
    return error;
}
```

here is the root of the issue, what happens when the `error` is an empty string `''`.

your type guard is bypassed.

instead use `typeof` type guard.

```
if (typeof error === 'string') {
    return error;
 }
```

[link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGygXigbynMYEQFxQDkcAzgCamFQC%20A3AFADGA9gHYnBQDucAlp6gAUASgIAFAE7MAtrxIQAPPAQA%20FGtYQuUSTLkRBgiRBLMEANwjD1UecAAqvaRGYBXYIevI1x0xYMYWDj4RKQUJFTUwgA0UACMAAxJwsIM9IKkIKyMUCI2aPRQUKCQUACSAKISEii2wBK8rADmUAD0rdwAFhCsxZ1yUAMl0BwNzYOcZMwmUKzMnI0AZhA1w1DMi1C%20rgicLNUQjMAIIPSFmCRZOYuu2cC8bLZwy7qy8iLiUm%20KANrKsawdggALpQAA%20UB%20gIQCFilWqwLUBSKRXqIHQ5xRUBY7E4vlqcB4-G4fA8qUxKOMwFcEl6P18AKBwIYWOo2LgwEYnVyKwk1mRWK2EGptMh0NhUF5F3KVQkzIp1HOivOOI4UCmAGUZML%20s0AOr8blCCjAOAEZReJEU1VmCAAOgQzCaghNcHJRWVRVVnB%20rtivOYcoJRM4JGeEFe%20hEaSKvE2gmGG0l1UDKGQqEIo0aTUI-IpVJpvQDEhZNDORQLos12uAuqaBtrLo5braHWU4NmQNiXG6vWJJE6bgQZCgACNoMp6FFo2cMpdsrlLRiiu1uIGANYkQabYuDLdwOpjFpwapwU6o8DQeE1VBZ5o-YHli5XKA3O4PXphl5fKOiHQ-%20QFD%20RBGRhUEIShLsZQRK0sTRZdBW9IUt1QQlSRJfgZ0FIURTpBlOzA0sPXZTluUEXk82wys6XFf1qmla95VZJUnyQ6tnFrbMGyNXJXXNRAlwFL02D8e1HWdV13TLFURJ9P1kykINUJDJ5vz0d5yXOOMeRTPkEIrYVCwUwNS0VAzcPVZgtQ4utuKbU1hCnYQZ3STIFzybwENXLgNy3bTdwGOBemYUcACtDmAc41mvWoMGcEgwyaEI7xaT1nwXN8jg-VSIwAgw-0jQDgIlcVwLFKDGNglF4KElEkPxZT0JDLDBWoyF8NKoiaBIrkdL02rzKMyCYTompSGguUurM6ThNxSzrJ1LjDVqeyzVgAT8mtETbQdJ1Vqk6akN9ZtRsDUFGv7cNCvymNtz6wNKMpQzRWLUzzja9jFv1Q19qc6MgA).